# How to remove all words which doesn't match the pattern?

Tags: search, regular-expression, substitute, global-command

I've the following content:

```
a1a foo bar buzz
foo b2b bar buzz
foo bar c3c buzz
foo bar buzz d4d
```

where I can match all words consisting only alpha characters by the following pattern:

```
/\<[a-zA-Z]*\>
```

Now, how can I  remove all words which doesn't match the pattern?

So the final content is:

```
foo bar buzz
foo bar buzz
foo bar buzz
foo bar buzz
```

---

I've checked [Search for lines not containing pattern](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_lines_not_containing_pattern) page, but without luck.

To remove *some* words patching the pattern, *global* command can be used:

```
:g/\<[a-zA-Z]*\>/;&
```

as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19529723/55075).

However when doing opposite:

```
:v/\<[a-zA-Z]*\>/;&
```

there is this message:

> Pattern found in every line

Comment: In this case, you could simply search for `\a\d\a` and remove that. But that doesn't answer the general question of *How to remove something that doesn't match a search*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `\@<!` (which is sometimes called "negative lookbehind"):

`/\<\w\+\>\(\<\a\+\>\)\@<!`

```
    \@<! Matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match just
         before what follows.
```

It is a bit tricky to understand at first:

1. Initially we try searching for all words (including ones with numbers) `/\<\w\+\>`.
2. Since we want some words to match and not others, we use a "zero-width" in this position to force certain text to match.  In this case, the text we want is words without a digit: `\<\a\+\>`.
3. We wrap the second pattern in `\(`...`\)\@<!`, which denotes the zero-width mentioned above.  We use `\(`...`\)` to create a single atom.

Now, to remove those words, we can use `:substitute`, but add `\s\?` to take care of the spaces.

`:%s/\<\w\+\>\(\<\a\+\>\)\@<!\s\?//g`

We can make this slightly shorter using `\v` very magic:

`:%s/\v<\w+>(<\a+>)@<!\s?//g`